# Accessing params with react-router-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm using react-router-redux (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux)

installed with

```
npm install --save react-router-redux@next
```

implemented like so:

```
<Route path='/resource/:id' component={Resource}/>
```

I'm trying to access the parameter for the id in the container, like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps)
  return {...state.resource, id: ownProps.params.id}
}
```

As shown in the react-router-redux docs.

I'm getting an error stating that ownProps.params is undefined however. So this works:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {...state.resource, id: ownProps.match.params.id}
}
```

When I log ownProps, however, I find that ownProps.match.params.id contains the id I require.

Is this a change in implementation or have I implemented the route wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you link to the react-router-redux docs where it says that? `Route`s have always been passed three props, `match`, `location`, and `history`.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux:

    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
          return {
        id: ownProps.params.id,
        filter: ownProps.location.query.filter
      };
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm install --save react-router-redux@next`

With above command, you probably have installed an alpha version of `react-router-redux` 5 and you are using it with react-router v4.

As they have mention in https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux readme, `react-router-redux` version 5 is currently being actively developed in [somewhere else](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux).

> This repo is for react-router-redux 4.x, which is only compatible with
>   react-router 2.x and 3.x
>
> The next version of react-router-redux will be 5.0.0 and will be
>   compatible with react-router 4.x. It is currently being actively
>   developed [over there](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux).

**So the documentation you are referring isn't valid for the version you are using.**

There is nothing wrong in your implementation and you can continue to access `params` via `match` of ownProps.

Answer (score 17):

I know that it's already closed question, but I think it would be helpful info for someone else

I'm using the same version and here is my solution for the task of getting params when you don't have access to `match`:

```
import { createMatchSelector } from 'react-router-redux';

const { params } = createMatchSelector({ path: '/resource/:id' })(state);

console.log(params.id);
```

I'm using it in a `redux-saga`, not in the component. 
And for your situation, it would be better to use `react-router` props and get params from `props.match.params.id`

Comment: Thank you! I am also using `redux-saga` and need to access route props

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Since it's beta version there are no docs. So source code for the rescue :)